# Alternatives of mutation in this scenario?

Tags: clojure

I wrote a computationally-intensive function (get-cand-info below) that is going to be called from pre-existing clojure code written by others.

```
(defn get-cand-info [model tuple]  ; my code which operates on 'tuple' and a hash-map called 'model'
 ; ....
   cand-info)

;; how my code get-cand-info is going to be called
(defn get-cand-scores [model]
  (let [tuples   (make-tuples model)]    
    (filter identity
        (pmap #(get-cand-info model %) tuples))))

(defn select-cand [model]
  (let [cands-with-scores   (get-cand-scores model)]
    ; Logic to work on cand-with-scores, finally returns one of
    ; the cand-info but not the model
    ))
```

After writing the new get-cand-info function I realized that it produces identical result hundreds of times for a end-user session, which is really a waste of resources.

Naturally, I was inclined to consider **memoize** but didn't want to incur the increased memory usage for the entire life of the program; across all user-sessions it can be a lot of unique data in the cache and the data from one user-session is not valid for another user-session anyway.  The 'model' parameter to my function seemed the perfect place to cache the result of get-cand-info as it stores data for one session.
However, if I return an updated model from my function it changes the contract of what my function returns. If I do modify the contract to return a new 'model' map with the new result assoc'ed into it, I would need to update code all the way up the call stack - which means changes to a lot of functions and something I want to avoid.

So I decided to change the model and mutate it in my node:

```
(defn get-cand [model tuple]  
  ; Fetch the cand-info from the model if available there
  (if-let [cand-info   ((deref (:cand-info model)) tuple)]
     cand-info
     ; Else calculate the cand-info, 
     ; ....
     ;store it in the model and return it
     (do
       (swap! (:cand-info model) assoc tuple cand-info)
       cand-info) ))
```

This does the job but leaves me wondering

1) Whether there's a better, more clojurey way of solving the problem?

2) Is the mutation likely to result in any performance penalty or other drawback? (I don't have large datasets yet to test the performance).

Would appreciate any insights/comments.

P.S. The user-sessions are typically no longer than 5 minutes, and the size of data to be stored in get-cand-info per session would be under 200 MB which can be GCed as soon as the session is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it just like you propose.  No need to use `dosync` & `alter` with a `ref` for this. Just use a local `atom` within each `model`. It can then be GC'd when the model is no longer being used.

---

**Update**

One alternative from Java is to used a LinkedHashMap.  You can set a max size and [override the `removeEldestEntry()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)) to control behavior.

---

Note that this syntax is slightly off, but I'm sure you know how to fix it:

```
((deref...
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized i could use atom as no updates were to be synchronized.  Will wait a couple days to see if there are any more answers.  Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That could be an alternative if our user-sessions ever grow to need eviction. (more info in my comment to Nico below)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to (1), your `get-cand` function looks to be of a very similar structure as [usage](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Using#putting-it-together) of [`clojure.core/cache`](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache). You could look into the FIFO/LIFO/TTL caches, which can also be simply wrapped in an atom for updating.

Regarding (2), while I don't think this actually counts as "mutation" (maybe an expert can clarify), I believe it's perfectly sensible to have large pre-calculations cached (after all [Lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table)s are pervasive in e.g. image processing, and they're basically pre-hydrated caches).

Comment: This would be mutation. They're modifying (mutating) a mutable object (an `atom`). It is a sensible use of it though, for lack of a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I was not aware of this cache library.  In my case, the user-sessions are not long running (usually under 5 minutes) and within a user-session the amount of data to be cached would not exceed a couple of hundred megabytes. Also the data is ready to be GC'ed as soon as a user-session ends, so the need to do elaborate cache management is not expected. it seems like simple caching in an atom would suffice for now. But I will keep this idea in my back-pocket.